# Abort в Release сборке

Tags: c, visual-studio

Код проверяет пароль и вызывает abort если пароль неправильный. Но в  Release сборке при неправильном пароле abort не вызывается. Что нужно сделать для того чтобы было предупреждение?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int check(FILE* file, char* password)
{
    char p;
    int i = 0;
    while( ((p = getc(file)) != EOF) && (password[i] != '\n'))
    {
        if (password[i] != p) return 0;
        i++;
    }
    if ((p == EOF) && (password[i] == '\n')) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char password[100];
    FILE* file = fopen("password.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error open txt");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("password: ");
    fgets(password, 100, stdin);
    if (check(file, password) == 0)
    {
        perror("encorrect");
        fclose(file);
        abort();
    }
    printf("correct");
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать `return -1`, как раньше?

Comment: Правильно написать функцию `check`. Проверьте в release-версии, что она возвращает (напишите отладочный вывод на экран, например). Кстати, вы в курсе, что `fgetc` возвращает `int`, а не `char`?

Comment: А что не так с функцией? Возвращает все правильно.